# Integral of Infinite Sines

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I constructed the following question:

Let $S_n$ denote the sequence where

\begin{align}
S_1=&\sin{x}\\
S_2=&\sin{(\sin{x})}\\
S_3=&\sin(\sin(\sin{x}))\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
Evaluate

$$I=\int_0^{\pi}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n\,dx$$

Messing around in desmos, it would seem that $S_n$ approaches $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. However I cant seem to be able to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: @Allawonder I'm not sure, furthermore, I'm not very experienced in analysis hence why I posted this to see the input of people with more experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $x_1 \in [0,\pi]$ the sequence defined by $ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ and $x_1$ converges to $0$: it is non negative and non increasing, hence converges. As $x \mapsto \sin x$ is continuous and $0$ is its only fix point, the limit is equal to zero.

Hence $ S_n$ converges pointwise to zero on $[0,\pi]$ and $$I=\int_0^{\pi}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n\,dx = 0$$

Comment: Why is the sequence eventually decreasing?

Comment: Because $0 < \sin x < x$ for $x \in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: Oh, that! $\qquad{{}}$

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Nice job (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The limit is where $S_n$ stops changing, in other words where the previous evaluation equals the next:

$$S_{n+1} "=" S_n \implies x = \sin x$$

which only has the solution $x=0$

Let's analyze this slightly more rigorously. Denote the sequential "derivative" of $S_n$ by $$S_{n+1} - S_n = \sin(S_n) - S_n$$

Since this gives the relationship between consecutive terms, we can figure out where the sequence is increasing or decreasing. For $S_n > 0$, the sequence will always decrease next, and for $S_n > 0$, it will always increase next.

Now we don't necessarily have monotonicity for arbitrary starting points, but consider that

$$|S_{n+1}| = |\sin(S_n)| < |S_n|$$

hence it will always grow closer to $0$ for any initial starting value in $\mathbb{R}$. Since we already proved that $0$ was a fixed point, we are done.

Comment: You may be correct, but I request a higher level of rigor. There is no $n\in\Bbb N$ with $S_{n+1}(x)\equiv S_n(x)$. Could you explain rigorously why we're allowed to solve the problem the way you propose? Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to write the same thing, but im also interested in a rigorous proof of this.

Comment: If you want more details, I suggest looking at [Fixed Point Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration), but let me give you a sketch. There is a reason why I put quotes around the equals sign, because it's shorthand for saying that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$$ Denoting $\lim S_n = L$, we get the following relation to solve: $$\sin(L) = L$$ The only condition needed is for $\sin(x)$ to be continuous.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  I second clathratus' comment.  I see no reason why $S_n(x)$ can't be bounded from below by some $\epsilon > 0$, where $S_n(x)$ is never equal to $\epsilon$, as $n$ goes to $\infty.$

Comment: Possible rebuttal to my own comment (above).  As $S_n(x)$ approaches $\epsilon$ (from above), its first derivative will approach $\cos(\epsilon)$ which must be close to 1.  This suggests a contradiction in my previous comment.  **I am out of my depth here and invite criticism of this comment, or my previous one.**

Comment: I am in the process of writing a detailed explanation

Comment: @clathratus Check the post now